# Openshift node app failed to start

Tags: node.js, deployment, openshift, sequelize.js

I am failing to start my node-based application on Openshift. The application starts OK locally but node's automatic deployment (on push to the remote master repo) hits a cyclic problem with the log;

```
DEBUG: Running node-supervisor with
DEBUG:   program './app/server.js'
DEBUG:   --watch '/var/lib/openshift/53dab282e0b8cdd367000131/app-root/data/.nodewatch'
DEBUG:   --ignore 'undefined'
DEBUG:   --extensions 'node|js|coffee'
DEBUG:   --exec 'node'
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node ./app/server.js'
DEBUG: Watching directory '/var/lib/openshift/53dab282e0b8cdd367000131/app-root/data/.nodewatch' for changes.
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'underscore.string'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/53dab282e0b8cdd367000131/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/sequelize/lib/utils.js:5:26)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
DEBUG: Program node ./app/server.js exited with code 8
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node ./app/server.js'
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'underscore.string'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/53dab282e0b8cdd367000131/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/sequelize/lib/utils.js:5:26)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
DEBUG: Program node ./app/server.js exited with code 8
```

...this loop continues indefinitely, the app reports "Started" but clearly it's failed to initialize *sequelize.js*.

I'm a bit lost and loosing the faith in Openshift hosting at this point. I think this might be the last straw. Any advice?

Here is my app's `package.json`;

```
{
  "name": "OceanLife-API",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "description": "OceanLife API",
  "keywords": [
    "OceanLife",
    "API",
    "tide",
    "swell",
    "weather"
  ],
  "author": {
    "name": "David Branton",
    "email": "oceanlife.development@gmail.com",
    "url": "http://oceanlifeapi-brantapps.rhcloud.com/"
  },
  "homepage": "http://oceanlifeapi-brantapps.rhcloud.com/",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/openshift/origin-server"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.25",
    "npm": ">= 1.3.24"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~3.4.8",
    "sleep": "~1.1.8",
    "aglio": "~1.14.0",
    "sequelize": "~1.7.10",
    "lodash": "~2.4.1",
    "mysql": "~2.4.3",
    "cheerio": "~0.17.0",
    "moment": "~2.9.0",
    "moment-timezone": "~0.2.5",
    "tzwhere": "~1.0.0",
    "line-reader": "~0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/jshint app/**/*.js",
    "pretest": "npm run-script lint",
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/istanbul cover ./node_modules/.bin/_mocha -- --recursive -R spec"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "istanbul": "~0.3.5",
    "rewire": "~2.1.3",
    "sinon": "~1.12.2",
    "mocha": "~2.1.0",
    "nock": "~0.57.0",
    "dredd": "~0.3.14",
    "jshint": "~2.5.11"
  },
  "bundleDependencies": [],
  "private": true,
  "main": "./app/server.js"
}
```

Comment: Is underscore.string properly installed?

Comment: Hey there, the openshift container is responsible for setting up the modules my app requires. The instructions i provide are under the package.json and i think it'll simply do an npm install on the directory route. But yea, looks like it's fluffed up sequelize.js...

Comment: Moving away from OpenShift now so I'm closing this question shortly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come back to this recently and have managed to get it working by using the community built Node v0.12 cartridge. If you are having similar issues I'd recommend ditching the "official" Node v0.1 app cartridge and trying again.

Sweet - free hosting of my node app! :D