# Openshift nodejs app says can't find module that is in node_modules

Tags: node.js, npm, openshift

I have a nodejs app on openshift but I am getting a startup error saying it can't find a module that actually is in the app-root/run-time/repo/node_modules folder. App works locally just fine. Appreciate any insight.

Comment: I have been getting similar errors with Openshift. See my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016236/openshift-node-app-failed-to-start . It appears the version of node being used on Openshift is very picky about how a new module is required. It's needy about where it is specified with a .js at the end or a ./ at the start. Currently working to find out if there are workarounds to this...